# Does the VideoCastManager support stopping of playback?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

How do you go about stopping the playback of a video? I only see a method for pausing.

Can I maybe force the load of a null video or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will be a version of CastCompanionLibrary that will be published soon which exposes stop and some more new features. In most cases, you don't really need to call stop since that unloads the video as well; you can simply pause. Are you dealing with live streams? What is your use case for calling stop?

Comment: It isn't live streams, they are locally served videos. I wanted to add stop because Youtube has that ability from the notification area (the little x on the corner) while other apps didn't and that always felt like something that was missing when I used those apps.

Comment: If you check out the CastVideos-android sample and run that, when you send the application to background (say, by clicking on the Home button), notification in the Notification Bar appears. If you open that, you'll see an "x" which stops the "application" not the "media", and removes the notification. That is the preferred action since we want to provide a very quick way for user to stop the application that is running on TV so we don't want to force them to first open the app and then stop the app, etc. (continued in the next comment due to the length restriction)

Comment: So if you want to follow the same pattern, that functionality is already there. In fact, if you are using CCL, you can easily use the notification and lock screen functionalities that it offers out of the box so you don't have to write the cod yourself.

Comment: That is one option I was considering. I am using the lockscreen from CCL but not the notification screen as I want to add a bit more functionality like fast forward and rewind. I already had a good notification layout done before CCL was released so I just need to adapt that. Thanks.

Comment: One more question, what happens after I stop the application using CCL, do I need to make any special calls if the user wants to do it again or does that just tell the chromecast to disconnect and all they'll have to do is reconnect?

Comment: stopApplication stops the application on the Cast device (sends you to the home screen there) and disconnects you from the cast device. So you would need to reconnect again if needed. If you still see that you need the stop (media) functionality very quickly, let me know and I'll see if I can add it ahead of schedule.

Comment: That sounds almost like what I want but I think a stop where the application stays connected to the chromecast would be a better user experience. But for now I think the `stopApplication` method will be enough. Thank you for all the help.